# Time out on Leetcode 160 Intersection of Two Linked Lists

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve [Leetcode 160. Intersection of Two Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/description/):

> Given the heads of two singly linked-lists `headA` and `headB`, return the node at which the two lists intersect. If the two linked lists have no intersection at all, return `null`.
>
> For example, the following two linked lists begin to intersect at node `c1`:
>
> [image]
>
> The test cases are generated such that there are no cycles anywhere in the entire linked structure.
>
> Note that the linked lists must retain their original structure after the function returns.

I wanted to use the two pointers to solve it, but the Leet Code site gives me a *Time Limit Exceeded* error.

My code is shown below:

```
ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {
    ListNode *tempA = headA, *tempB = headB;
    while (tempA != tempB) {
        if (tempA->next != NULL) { tempA = tempA->next;}
        else { tempA->next = headB;}
        if (tempB->next != NULL) { tempB = tempB->next;}
        else { tempB->next = headA; }
    }
    return tempA;
}
```

I then tried this existing solution and it works, but I cannot tell what's different:

```
ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {
    ListNode *tempA = headA, *tempB = headB;
    while (tempA != tempB) {
        if (tempA != NULL) { tempA = tempA->next;}
        else { tempA = headB;}
        if (tempB != NULL) { tempB = tempB->next;}
        else { tempB = headA;}
    }
    return tempA;
}
```

Comment: `tempA = headB;` isn't the same as `tempA->next = headB;`  Same with the next one. It would be trivial to rearrange one of the examples to match the other in the order things are done so it would be easier to see how they differ.

Comment: Thanks. so you mean `tempA = headB;` will let tempA traverse the list B in the following `tempA = tempA->next;` , while `tempA->next = headB;` will not do the same thing?

Comment: You said you cannot tell what's different. That's something that is. The conditions are different as well.

Comment: I'm confused why using `tempA->next = headB;` will not traverse the list B in the following `tempA = tempA->next;`  Maybe it is a stupid question, while I'm a beginner in cs....

Comment: *but I get a TLE.* -- Do not use abbreviations such as "TLE".  Most C++ programmers do not go to sites like Leetcode, and thus those abbreviations are not known.  Use full words, not abbreviations.  Second, your problem is easily solved if you simply added the nodes to a `std::unordered_set<ListNode*>` from the first linked list, and then traverse the second linked list to see if the node exists in the set you created.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that your solution that fails never terminates on two distinct lists (i.e. no nodes in common) with different lengths.

Comment: It's hard to believe that you could come up with such a clever algorithm without knowing how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm should be a "read-only" algorithm, i.e. there should be no reason to modify the linked lists to determine the solution.

Yet, that is what the first version of the code does: it assigns a new reference to a node's `next` property. This should never happen: there is no good reason why a node's `next` property would need to get a new value when the only thing you want to do is "calculate" where a certain node is located and return it.

In this particular case `tempA->next = headB;` is linking the end of linked list A with the start of linked list B. To picture this, let's imagine the two lists are initially like this:

```
                              tempA
                               ↓
                             ┌────────────┐
                    headA:─► │ data: 2    │
                             │ next: ───────┐
                             └────────────┘ │    ┌────────────┐
                                            └──► │ data: 3    │
                                            ┌──► │ next: NULL │
         ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐ │    └────────────┘     
headB:─► │ data: 4    │      │ data: 5    │ │
         │ next: ──────────► │ next: ───────┘
         └────────────┘      └────────────┘     
           ↑
          tempB
```

The loop will in the first iterations always execute the `if` cases, and so after one iteration `tempA` and `tempB` will reference the next nodes:

```
                             ┌────────────┐
                    headA:─► │ data: 2    │          tempA
                             │ next: ───────┐         ↓
                             └────────────┘ │    ┌────────────┐
                                            └──► │ data: 3    │
                                            ┌──► │ next: NULL │
         ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐ │    └────────────┘     
headB:─► │ data: 4    │      │ data: 5    │ │
         │ next: ──────────► │ next: ───────┘
         └────────────┘      └────────────┘     
                               ↑
                              tempB
```

And now, in the second iteration, the first `else` block will execute `tempA->next = headB;` which *alters* that tail node's `next` property, bringing about the following situation:

```
                             ┌────────────┐
                    headA:─► │ data: 2    │          tempA
                             │ next: ───────┐         ↓
                             └────────────┘ │    ┌────────────┐
                                            └──► │ data: 3    │
                                            ┌──► │ next: ────────┐
         ┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐ │    └────────────┘  │  
headB:─► │ data: 4    │      │ data: 5    │ │                    │
     ┌─► │ next: ──────────► │ next: ───────┘                    │
     │   └────────────┘      └────────────┘                      │
     └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                               ↑
                              tempB
```

This is introducing a cycle in the linked list: there is now no more tail node -- there is no node anymore whose  `next` property is `NULL`. As you can see that means the `while` condition will from now on *always* be true,... this has become an infinite loop. This explains why the platform that runs this code is signaling a "time limit exceeded" error.

Comment: I think that example is not one of the failing cases. That reaches the loop exit condition `while (tempA != tempB)` when both `tempA` and `tempB` are references to the node with `data: 3`

Comment: About "read-only": There's a [fantastic solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/discuss/49899/C++-solution-using-XOR-trick) that does involve rewiring and restoring the lists.